# ASP.NET core 2.0 facebook JWT authentication

Tags: asp.net, facebook, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm trying to make JWT Facebook authentication, with ASP.NET core 2.0.

ConfigureServices:

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddJwtBearer(options =>
                {
                    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        ValidateIssuer = true,
                        ValidateAudience = true,
                        ValidateLifetime = true,
                        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                        ValidIssuer = Configuration["Authentication:JWT:Issuer"],
                        ValidAudience = Configuration["Authentication:JWT:Issuer"],
                        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["Authentication:JWT:Key"]))
                    };
                })
                .AddFacebook(facebookOptions =>
                {
                    facebookOptions.AppId = Configuration["Authentication:Facebook:AppId"];
                    facebookOptions.AppSecret = Configuration["Authentication:Facebook:AppSecret"];
                    facebookOptions.CallbackPath = Configuration["Authentication:Facebook:CallbackUrl"];
                });
```

Configure

```
app.UseAuthentication();
```

When I'm trying to make login, in Facebook login callback there is error:

> InvalidOperationException: No IAuthenticationSignInHandler is
>   configured to handle sign in for the scheme: Bearer

When I'm making Cookie authentication, without JWT it works.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I have not integrated Facebook with JWTs but the fact cookie authentication is working suggests that your app is configured for Cookie authentication only rather than JWT.

try inserting `options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;` into your `services.AddAuthentication`

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
});
```

Comment: if my answer doesn't help you  have a look at this post on authentication in asp.net Core 2.0 https://fullstackmark.com/post/13/jwt-authentication-with-aspnet-core-2-web-api-angular-5-net-core-identity-and-facebook-login